# Is compiling ELF files with MSB flag possible in Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, elf

Is it possible to compile binary files with MSB endianness in GCC? If so, would they work correctly when executed?

Comment: On which architecture?  On SPARC or Power, you'd probably find MSB is the default.  On Intel, probably you can't.

Comment: On Intel. If I somehow altered every ELF header entry to MSB in a little-endian binary, would that execute properly?

Comment: No; you'd have to make lots of other changes to the code to give it the slightest chance of working.  Basically, every number would have to be reworked from little-endian to big-endian.

Comment: Would that include instruction addresses, immediate parameters etc.? I would assume that regardless of the ELF flag, these should remain little-endian

Comment: I think it is time for you to go and try it.  I'm not sure, and I'm not willing to put much effort into thinking about it — it seems to me like an exercise in futility.  With just a modicum of further thought, I think there's a very  chance high chance that the kernel for Intel will simply decline to execute the MSB ELF executable; it was compiled to expect LSB and knows it doesn't know how to deal with the alternative.  To fix that, you'd have to rebuild the kernel and the dynamic loader, `ld.so.1`.  And the best of British to you.

Comment: You have to use cross toolchain in order to produce big endian code on little endian host. Because there is another places in the code that take care of endianes, functions such as network `htons` and friends what cannot be ease fixed in compiled code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm writing a code that will modify elf headers for Intel binaries specifically, and was wondering if I should spend time handling the MSB case. This has been very helpful <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments into something resembling an answer.*</sup>

In part, it depends on the CPU architecture. On SPARC or Power, you'd probably find MSB is the default. On Intel, which is definitely LSB by default, you probably can't.

> On Intel. If I somehow altered every ELF header entry to MSB in a little-endian binary, would that execute properly?

No; you'd have to make lots of other changes to the code to give it the slightest chance of working. Basically, every number would have to be reworked from little-endian to big-endian.

> Would that include instruction addresses, immediate parameters etc.? I would assume that regardless of the ELF flag, these should remain little-endian.

With just a modicum of further thought, I think there's a very chance high chance that the kernel for Intel will simply decline to execute the MSB ELF executable. It was compiled to expect LSB and knows it doesn't know how to deal with the alternative. To fix that, you'd have to rebuild the kernel and the dynamic loader, `ld.so.1`. And that's probably just the start of your problems.

On the whole, I would regard this as an exercise in futility.  In the absence of information to the contrary, I don't think you need to worry about handling the headers of MSB ELF headers for Intel binaries; they won't exist in practice.

Answer (score 1):

It do not think it is explicitely stated in the [System V ABI](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf) but AFAIK, the ELF file is expected to be in native endianness (and `e_ident[EI_DATA]` describes the endianess used):

> Byte `e_ident[EI_DATA]` specifies the data encoding of the
>   processor-specific data in the object file. The following encodings
>   are currently defined.

You might expect the processor-specific data to be in the processor endianness. For example, the content of the `.got` is processor-specific data and you definitely want it to be in native endianness.

On Intel computers, you have to use the `ELFDATA2LSB`.

From the [System V ABI ~ Intel386 Supplement 4th edition](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf):

> For file identification in `e_ident`, the Intel386 architecture
>   requires the following  values.
>
> ```
> e_ident[EI_CLASS] = ELFCLASS32
> e_ident[EI_DATA]  = ELFDATA2LSB
> ```

From the [System V ABI ~ AMD64 supplement Draft 0.99.6](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi-0.99.6.pdf):

> For file identification in `e_ident`, the AMD64 architecture
>   requires the following  values.
>
> ```
> e_ident[EI_CLASS] = ELFCLASS64
> e_ident[EI_DATA]  = ELFDATA2LSB
> ```